# PHP - GET Method adds unnecessary additions symbols to URL

Tags: php, html, get

I looked around Stack Overflow for the recommended method type for PHP; either the GET or POST  method. Recommended by the community, the GET method seems to be a good idea for passing queries for a simple search engine.

Unfortunately, the GET method adds unnecessary addition symbols to the URL to indicate spaces. Basically, a aesthetic issue.

I tried the `trim()` function to lessen the spaces, however, that is only called after the data is submitted and the URL is already set with the parameters.

Here is a the index.php file I think is not cooperating with me.

```
<?php $query = ""; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter Query">
            <input type="submit" text="Search">
        </form>

        <?php
            $query = $_GET['query'];
            print $query;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

A example, if needed. If I type into the search bar this query...

`sample              1`

The URL will be formed this way...

`http://localhost/search/index.php?query=sample++++++++++++++1`

Is there a way to fix this problem or is the POST method the only way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the POST method.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter Query">
        <input type="submit" text="Search">
    </form>

    <?php
        $query = $_GET['query'];
        print $query;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use     `urlencode` or `str_replace`.
`urlencode` will replace all spaces with plus symbols, and with `str_replace` you can replace either underscores with plus symbols, or spaces with minus symbols.

Replace spaces with underscores:     `str_replace(' ', '_', $url);`

Urlencode your `$_GET*`: `urlencode($url);`

Comment: That seems like a potential method I can use. Just need some nudge where to put it...